# I get 404 Error while creating a site based on custom site template

Tags: sharepoint

I have to move a site from one server to another. I saved the site as a template and uploaded to the site templates of another server. Now when i try to create a site in the destination server using that template then it redirects me to a 404 error page which says

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I dont have any access to the destination server but the site which i am working in I am the site collection admin.

Any Suggestions are highly appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

Check the root path you have declared.
Maybe you left the old one.